# Toast message not displaying, gets warning: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view

Tags: android, android-view

Below is my code, that is displaying a progress dialog box to authenticate the user.
I want to display a Toast message, when userid or password does not match(response code not 200)
but i am getting a warning

```
WARN/InputManagerService(58): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy
```

and toast message does not display

**code**

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
                try {
                    performBackgroundProcess();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                }.start();



    private void performBackgroundProcess() {
        String sUserName = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
        String sPassword = String authentication = sUserName + ":" + sPassword;
        String login = Base64.encodeToString(authentication.getBytes(),
                            Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Resources res = getResources();
        String URLLogin = res.getString(R.string.URLlogin);
        RestClient client = new RestClient(URLLogin, login);
        try {
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (client.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username or Password does not match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

See whatever UI changes, toast, dialog box you want to have , you cannot have on another thread. You have to do that on main UI thread. An easy way for you right is making use of handler as using aync now will have to make many changes.

```
  new Handler().post( new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username or Password does not match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
          });

    }
```

Handler of android.os not of java here.

Comment: vikky: by your code progressDialog keeps running, means this thraed does not run. i have written it in if(client.response!=200){

Comment: ok. create instance of handler in activity  like Handler handler = new Handler();

Comment: still getting the warning in log, but ya toast displayed :)

Answer (score 0):

I Think You are running code in background so Toast will not work there you have to write Toast on UI thread not on Background.. because this thread can not update UI thread.. I suggest you use AsyncTask for Threading its very clean and easy to use

Comment: as far as i know ,there is no code running in background, after getting response i want to display toast...anyway if problem can be solved using Async task, would you please give me example or please edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the scope getApplicationcontext give it as 'this' or 'ActivityName.class' and check .
Didnt check it , but might work.

Comment: this or ActivityName.class giving error, i used ActivityName.this but did not work